# In tidyr::pivot_wider, `values_fn = sum(.,na.rm=TRUE)` failed

Tags: r, tidyr

In tidyr::pivot_wider, `values_fn = sum(.,na.rm=TRUE)` failed ,how to handle it?

```
library(tidyverse)
test_data <- data.frame(
  category=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'),
  sub_category=c('a','b','b','a','b','b'),
  amount=1:6
)

test_data %>% pivot_wider(names_from ='category',
                          values_from ='amount' ,
                          values_fn = sum(.,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it a function to handle this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
test_data <- data.frame(
  category=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'),
  sub_category=c('a','b','b','a','b','b'),
  amount=1:6
)

test_data %>% pivot_wider(names_from ='category',
                          values_from ='amount' ,
                          values_fn = function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   sub_category     A     B
#>   <chr>        <int> <int>
#> 1 a                1     4
#> 2 b                5    11
```

The new syntax for making an anonymous function (`\(x)`) works too:

```r
test_data %>% pivot_wider(names_from ='category',
                          values_from ='amount' ,
                          values_fn = \(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   sub_category     A     B
#>   <chr>        <int> <int>
#> 1 a                1     4
#> 2 b                5    11
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: If you're interested, someone's done a test on what works and what doesn't here https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1114 :)